# Caffe Compilation Error with "adadelta_solver"

Tags: compiler-errors, caffe, nvcc

I am trying to compile caffe, but I get this error:

> NVCC src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.cu nvcc fatal   : A single
>   input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is
>   specified Makefile:594: recipe for target
>   '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.o' failed make:
>   *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.o] Error 1

Could you help me figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

comment both USE_CUDNN := 1 and CPU_ONLY := 1 in Makefile.config .
Then execute below comamnds,

```
$ cmake . 
$ make -j 4 all
```